Too much space in app name CFBundleDisplayName
I am building react native ios project and there is too much space in the app name, I have tried the following but still the space is double.
1.
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>App&#x2007;Name</string>




<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>App Name</string> 




<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>App&#x0020;Name</string>




<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>App&#32;Name</string>

I have tried all 4 of the above things and the space is still double both on emulator and original devices.

The issue you're facing is due to the way iOS handles whitespace characters in the CFBundleDisplayName key. Try using the following:
XML
CFBundleDisplayName
App Name
Notice the character between "App" and "Name" is a Unicode character U+2007 Figure Space, not a regular space. This should fix the double space issue.
If the above solution doesn't work, try setting the CFBundleDisplayName key in your app's Info.plist file using Xcode's built-in property list editor. Sometimes, manually editing the plist file can lead to unexpected results.
